# Ruby & Watir... Web Drivers Conflict

Tags: ruby, watir

I've downloaded and installed the latest version of Ruby Ruby+Devkit 3.2.2.1(x64) from this link:https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Run the command prompt with Ruby and run:

```
gem install watir
gem install webdrivers
```

Run interactive Ruby, and run:

```
require 'Watir'
require 'webdrivers'
```

and get an error as below:

```
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2295:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate webdrivers-5.3.1, because selenium-webdriver-4.13.1 conflicts with selenium-webdriver (~> 4.0, < 4.11) (Gem::ConflictError)
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1424:in `activate'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems.rb:209:in `rescue in try_activate'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems.rb:202:in `try_activate'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:154:in `rescue in require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:39:in `require'
        from (irb):2:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/irb-1.6.2/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/irb:33:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/irb:33:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2295:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate webdrivers-5.3.1, because selenium-webdriver-4.13.1 conflicts with selenium-webdriver (~> 4.0, < 4.11) (Gem::ConflictError)
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1424:in `activate'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems.rb:203:in `try_activate'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:154:in `rescue in require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:39:in `require'
        from (irb):2:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/irb-1.6.2/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/irb:33:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/irb:33:in `<main>'
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- webdrivers (LoadError)
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from (irb):2:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/irb-1.6.2/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/irb:33:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/irb:33:in `<main>'
```

What have I done wrong? Literally followed instructions step by step on how to install it...

I tried uninstalling and re-installing Ruby, and then running 'Require Webdrivers' without installing them first, as I thought the conflict might result from some pre-installed drivers from when Ruby was installed, but nothing was called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium manages drivers directly now (and better than the webdrivers gem does), so you do not need webdrivers gem any more. Remove the requirement and it will just work.

Discussion of details and reasons can be found here:
https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers/#update-future-of-this-project

Comment: Hello, I’ll remove this message once I receive a response from you. You’re managing the watir.github.io page on GitHub for the Watir website, correct? While GitHub allows for the creation of one page per repository, I’m curious as to how you’re able to create a new page for each release. Do you create a new project for each new page release? Also, how is the watir.github.io page linked to watir.com? Is there a fee associated with the watir.com domain?

Comment: You can read up on github pages. Watir is using Jekyll to generate a static site, and Github can generate it and host it. Then we set up the domain host to allow directing the domain to github, and manage in repo with CNAME file. https://github.com/watir/watir.github.io/

Comment: I read there , but in pages it says, we can create one page for repository. But you keep adding pages for every releases, that's where my question was. How have been doing this?

Comment: Oh, this is for the org as a whole. See, it's the org name not the repo name (e.g., "seleniumhq" not "selenium" — https://github.com/seleniumhq/seleniumhq.github.io)

Comment: No, I was not asking this, I was asking about the pages you upload in watir.com. every releases you create a new page, right? How are you doing that in github.io? I heard it allows to create one page per project.

Comment: I don't know where you are getting the one page limit. So many examples out there of building large static sites on Github Pages.

Comment: Okay, let me check it. thanks for information.